# Can you get the public IP address of an EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi there im new to python code and was wondering is there a way of creating an instance and then printing the IP address back to the console, at the moment i can create an instance and it prints the instance ID back

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-0713f98de93617bb4',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    KeyName='JamieTest',
    SecurityGroupIds=['sg-0273f9f172ba795ab'],
    InstanceType='t2.nano')
print ('Your instance has been created, the instance ID is :' + instance[0].id)
```

Comment: It should be in `instance[0].public_ip_address`. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.public_ip_address

Comment: so if i do this, print ('Your instance has been created, the instance ID is :' + instance[0].id), + instance[0].public_ip_address) it wont work because it takes a few seconds for the ip to be created is there a way of telling it to wait until the instance is running before it prints it?

Comment: You can check if the instance state is running before printing the id.
`if instance[0].state['Name'] == 'running': print('your instance ip address' + instance[0].public_ip_address)`

Answer (score 0):

[create_instances()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) returns a list of [ec2.Instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance) objects and each may have a `public_ip_address` property (if the instance has a public IP address).

Thus

```py
print ('Your instance public IP address is : ' + instance[0].public_ip_address)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this but because my instance is being created and this is running straight after there is no ip adresss for a few seconds, is there a way of telling a command to wait before running?

Comment: @JamieHogan better would be to make another request to get the instance by ID and check if the IP address appeared. See this method: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Comment: @JamieHogan you should use this Boto3 waiter to wait for the instance to be running, then you should be able to get the IP address: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning

Answer (score 0):

You may use `describe_instances()` method:

```py
import time

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
ec2_client = session.client('ec2')
instance_id = instance[0].id #your instance id here

cycle = True
    while cycle:
        time.sleep(0.1)  #any value of your choice              
        allinstances = ec2_client.describe_instances().get('Reservations')
        for i, group in enumerate(allinstances):
             for j, instance in enumerate(group.get('Instances')):
                  if instance.get("InstanceId") == instance_id:
                      externalip = instance.get('PublicIpAddress')
                      if externalip is not None: cycle = False
print('External IP:', externalip)
```